# Powershell Command open from location and run command

Tags: powershell

Learning how to use powershell.  But what I am trying to do is from a specific location open a command prompt  then execute a command.

So far I've been able to set the location and open the command prompt but can not run  a command

so far i've tried this

```
Set-Location "F:\Projects\GameManagement\server"
start cmd.exe
```

And I've also tried the start process but dont know how to set the location and open with a specific program

The command i am trying to send to the command prompt is 'nodemon index.js'.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `cmd.exe`, PowerShell is a *shell*, which means that you can invoke console applications *directly*, which executes them *synchronously*:

```
Set-Location F:\Projects\GameManagement\server
nodemon index.js
```

If the `nodemon` executable too is located in `F:\Projects\GameManagement\server`, you must replace the last line with
`.\nodemon index.js`,  as [Robert Cotterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035141/robert-cotterman) points out, because, PowerShell, unlike `cmd.exe`, does not permit invocation of executables located in the current directory by name only, for security reasons.

From within PowerShell there is rarely a need to call `cmd.exe` - just use PowerShell itself.

Comment: my guess is he might need `.\nodemon index.js` or he could just do `$path = "F:\Projects\GameManagement\server"` followed by `invoke-expression "$path\nodemon $path\index.js"` the set-location would ensure it works inside that folder

Comment: Good tip re `.\nodemon`, @RobertCotterman, thanks; I've added it to the answer. However, there is no need for `Invoke-Expression` here, which [should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: I try to answer what I understand in a way all variants can be answered. As other users may some day read this and can figure it out better. Anyhow thanks for the vote of confidence. The invoke-expression was there to ensure the variable was utilized in the command. Maybe I misunderstand how it works.

Comment: @RobertCotterman: Use `&`, the call operator, to invoke executables specified via a quoted string and/or via a variable reference: `& $path\nodemon $path\index.js`

Comment: that works searching for a way now to kill the process @mklement0

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TroyBryant. To kill processes in PowerShell, use the [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) cmdlet.